Maven exception: has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0)
i wrote default java spring code built by maven, but i have this exception:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of
the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
i tried to figure it out by myself, but it dont work. I deleted and downloaded my java, checked dependencies, but nothing work. You can see my project in my github repo, in package "demo" https://github.com/tonkaxxx/test

The springframework (my assumption is that you are using spring boot 3.0.0+). This requires JDK17+

... and you are using Java 8. Please upgrade your java version, and please build with at least code-level 17 (better: 21).

when im trying to change my java version, i see this:
'demo' is imported by Maven, changes made to the classpath might be lost after reloading. To make permanent changes, please edit the
pom.xml file.

You don't need to do anything to your pom. There's no Java version set in there anyway. You need to have a >= Java 17 compiler in your PATH when the pom is used

if i change i have this problem:
The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 21 is used

Don't be dictated to by your IDE. Change to JDK >= 17 and do mvn clean compile at the command line and your project compiles

it gives me: "command not found"

Again, you're IDE-led. You should have, if developing with Java, Maven installed independently and placed in your PATH. At least one of those things you don't have
